# Somar itens da tabela 1 e trazer rows indexadas pelo codigo da tabela 2

Tags: sql, postgresql

Sou muito novato com SQL e estou criando um aplicativo que traz o numero de horas contratadas, bom a parte que tenho dúvidas na query é o index das linhas...

Eu preciso que as linhas não repitam o código da tabela 1 e somem os itens da tabela 2.

Meu código é esse:

```
SELECT tabela1.codigo_tabela2, SUM(tabela1.itens), tabela2.nome, tabela2.codigo
    FROM tabela1, tabela2
    WHERE tabela1.codigo_tabela2 = tabela2.codigo AND tabela1.ativo = b'1' AND tabela1.usuario = x
```

Bom, espero que consigam me ajudar... Não consegui encontrar nada nas minhas pesquisas, (é bem específico).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    tabela2.nome, 
    tabela2.codigo,
    SUM(tabela1.itens)
FROM tabela1, tabela2
WHERE 
    tabela1.codigo_tabela2 = tabela2.codigo AND 
    tabela1.ativo = b'1' AND  
    tabela1.usuario = x
GROUP BY
    tabela2.nome, 
    tabela2.codigo
```

Comment: Valeu, eu não conhecia esse _statement_ **"GROUP BY"**. :D Ah! Eu retirei o tabela2.codigo do SELECT, mas a mantive no GROUP BY @mxix